# How to search/find for multiple format styles in VBA for Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this.

I would like to code the Find function in Word 2013 for searching specific words in multiple styles. Not even sure if this is possible because Word doesn't have that option in Advanced Find --> More --> Format --> Style. It only allows for filtering one style.

My goal is to be able to find paragraph marks (syntax: ^p) on styles 'Heading 1' through 'Heading 9'.

```
Sub AppendixFix()

    ' Declaring variables
    Dim multiStyles As String, i As Integer
    multiStyles = "Heading 1, Heading 2, Heading 3, Heading 4, Heading 5, Heading 6, Heading 7, Heading 8, Heading 9"

    ' Start at the top of document and clear find formatting
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

    ' Navigate to Appendix section
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Appendix"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = True
        .Execute
    End With

    ' Loop until find is not found and limit to 1000 counts
    Do While Selection.Find.Found = True And i < 1000
        i = i + 1
        ' Add text to the beginning of each line
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.TypeText Text:=" *Test* "
        ' Navigate to the next heading by looking at following paragraph mark
        Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(multiStyles)
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "^p"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = True
            .Execute
            .Execute
        End With
    Loop

End Sub
```

I expected the code to start inputting *Test* at the first 'Appendix' heading, then inputs *Test* to its sub-headings (Heading 2, 3..., 9), and continues to the end of the document. However, it only adds the text to Heading 1-styled headers skipping its sub-headers. It seems to me that only the first style in the list gets read in. I've tried removing Heading 1 from the list and it checks for Heading 2-styled headers.

Comment: I think the better option here is to search ALL text, and test against the `.Style` property of the selected text. You could say `If InStr(multiStyles, Selection.Style) Then` to test the `True` condition.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that function. Where would I place it in my code? Also, I would like to only modify the headings from Appendix and below so I don't think I should search ALL texts.

Comment: Ah I see what you're trying to do now - did you get this code from somewhere else? What your trying to do won't work, you need to iterate through an array. I'll try to fix it up now.

Comment: I tried putting in the InStr code before the Do While loop but nothing happened. It's my own code that I pieced together from different ideas. The end goal is actually to delete the first 2 or 3 characters of each header instead of inserting *Test*. I'll also need to figure out how to identify the first 2 characters of each header as numbers before deleting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me in a test document based on what I understand the set up of the document in the question is.

The code needs to loop the styles. In order to do this, the styles need to be in something that can be looped - an ***array***. The `Split` method splits up a list into an array, based on a ***delimiter***. The delimiter can be only one character, so the spaces after the commas need to be removed from `multiStyles` in the code in the question.

When looping, it's important to return to the starting point (Appendix) for each style. For that, the code below uses a `Range` object.

The "Test" text should only be added if something is found. The code below uses a boolean variable to store what `Find.Execute` returns (true if found) so that this as well as the `Loop Until` can be tested reliably.

It's possible that a Find can end up at the end of the document. In that case, the code goes into an endless loop, so there's a test for the end position to move to the next style in the list.

```
Sub AppendixFix()

    ' Declaring variables
    Dim multiStyles As String, i As Integer
    Dim aStyleList As Variant
    Dim counter As Long, s As String, found As Boolean
    Dim rngStart As Range

    multiStyles = "Heading 1,Heading 2,Heading 3,Heading 4,Heading 5,Heading 6,Heading 7,Heading 8,Heading 9"
    aStyleList = Split(multiStyles, ",")

    ' Start at the top of document and clear find formatting
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

    ' Navigate to Appendix section
    Selection.Find.style = ActiveDocument.styles("Heading 1")
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Appendix"
        .Forward = True
        .wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .Execute
    End With
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" *Test* "
    Selection.MoveStart wdParagraph, 1
    Set rngStart = Selection.Range.Duplicate

    ' Loop through all the styles in the list
    For counter = LBound(aStyleList) To UBound(aStyleList)
        'Loop as long as the style is found
        Do
            s = aStyleList(counter)
            With Selection.Find
                .style = ActiveDocument.styles(s)
                .Text = "^p"
                .Forward = True
                .wrap = wdFindStop
                .Format = True
                found = .Execute
            End With

            ' Add text to the beginning of each line
            If found Then
                Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
                Selection.TypeText Text:=" *Test* "
                Selection.MoveStart wdParagraph, 1
            End If
            If Selection.Start = ActiveDocument.content.End - 1 Then
                'End of Document, then loop to next style in list
                Exit For
            End If
        Loop Until found = False
        'start back at the Appendix for the next style
        rngStart.Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot - this will add test to the end of each of your headers, I believe. It's hard to tell what you're trying to do from your question.

```
Sub AppendixFix()

    ' Declaring variables
    Dim multiStyles As Variant, i As Integer
    multiStyles = Array("Heading 1", "Heading 2", "Heading 3", "Heading 4", "Heading 5", "Heading 6", "Heading 7", "Heading 8", "Heading 9")

    ' Start at the top of document and clear find formatting
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

    ' Navigate to Appendix section
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Appendix"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = True
        .Execute
    End With

    ' Loop until find is not found and limit to 1000 counts
    Do While Selection.Find.Found = True And i < 1000
        i = i + 1
        ' Add text to the beginning of each line
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.TypeText Text:=" *Test* "
        ' Navigate to the next heading by looking at following paragraph mark
        For j = 0 To UBound(multiStyles)
            Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(multiStyles(j))
            With Selection.Find
                .Text = "^p"
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindStop
                .Format = True
                .Execute
                .Execute
            End With
            Selection.TypeText Text:=" *Test* "
        Next j
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate your help so far. With your code, it searches for the paragraph mark by cycling through the style array. By doing this, it's also skipping a lot of sub-headings instead of checking each header below the Appendix. Is there a way to code this to not cycle through the array but to check if each header matches the list of styles that we included? Similar to an IF statement with lots of OR operations?

Comment: To elaborate on my question/goal, I'm trying to get rid of the numbering and white space or period for headings such as '4 Appendix A', '4.1 Intro', '5 Appendix B', '10.1.2 Appendix J...'. By inserting a *Test* at the front of each header, I can easily see my changes. I would modify my code later to execute the deletions but I'm still not sure how I will distinguish double-digit from single-digit numbering. Maybe I'll have to use the Selection.Find with .Text="^#^#". I've found that Find and Replace is too slow/crashes.